# Do Windows Mobile 6.5 applications work on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile-6.5

And if not then what do I have to do to make them?

(Our apps are in latest C# .NET.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of the C# sharp code is most likely the same but some things like saving and loading are different as well as you having a choice between XNA and Silverlight. The link below should contain a lot of the information you need.

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/

Answer (score 2):

No.  You would need to port your apps to the WP7 platform. You may be able to reuse some code, but the UI model is completely different.